# How is simultaneous i2c bus access handled by Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, i2c

I have two sensors with different slave addresses connected on an i2c bus in my custom board. If two different programs try to read the different sensors a same moment of time, will it lead to an contention in i2c subsystem for Linux kernel?

I tried doing that on the board with both the sensors but was not able to produce the contention. And didn't find any definitive documentation which suggest either way.

Is there any document which explains how a simultaneous read call to different slave address on a given i2c bus is handled by Linux kernel?

Comment: As far as I remember, there is a simple semaphore for each I2C bus, locking access to that bus during the operation.

Comment: In that case, it should be safe to use it from multiple thread/processes and i2c subsystem should be able to manage contention.

Comment: Yes, surely it is.